# How can I move this virtual method call out of the constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I've got a couple of classes that form a too-complicated object graph. Here's a peek at a smaller scenario. Assume INotifyPropertyChanged is in place.

```
class A
{
    public InternalType InterestingProperty { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public A Component { get; set; }
}
```

My helper class watches for these events and updates its properties when the properties of the objects change. It does this so some other class that's interested in about a dozen properties on as many objects are easily accessible. This is all packed in a framework that has several variants, so inheritance is in play.

I've finished the first scenario, and ended up with a concrete class like this:

```
class ScenarioOnePropertySpy
{
    protected ScenarioOne PropertySpy(Foo thingToMonitor)
    {
        _thingToMonitor = thingToMonitor;
        RegisterForEvents()
    }

    public B InterestingB { get; }

    protected RegisterForEvents()
    {
        // * Register for _thingToMonitor propertyChanged if first time.
        // * If B is different, unregister the old and register the new.
        // * If B hasn't been set yet register for PropertyChanged on it.
        // * If B.Component isn't the same as last time unregister the
        //      old and register the new.
    }

    protected Update()
    {
        // Some monitored object changed; refresh property values and
        // update events in case some monitored object was replaced.
        B = _thingToMonitor.B;
        RegisterForEvents()
    }

    private Handle_PropertyChanged(...) { Update(); } 
}
```

It's icky event registration, but moving that ugliness out of the class that wants to know about the properties is the purpose. Now I've moved on to scenario 2 that monitors different objects/properties and used my concrete class as a guide for an abstract one:

```
abstract class PropertySpy
{
    protected PropertySpy(FooBase thingToMonitor)
    {
        _thingToMonitor = thingToMonitor;
        RegisterForEvents()
    }

    protected abstract void RegisterForEvents()

    // ...
}
```

Whoops. I've got a virtual method call in the constructor. In theory it's safe for all of my scenarios, but the R# warning keeps digging at me. I'm sure if I move forward one day it's going to cause a problem that'll take a while to figure out. That method's definitely going to need to work with properties on the derived types.

I could drop the method and force derived types to do the event management themselves. That'd defeat the purpose for the base class. And someone would forget to follow the contract and it'd turn into a support incident; I spend enough time writing documentation as it is. Another one I thought of was making RegisterForEvents() publich and requiring users to call it after construction. That "create then initialize" pattern stinks in .NET and people always forget.  Currently I'm toying with the notion of another class that does the event registration that's injected via the constructor. Then derived classes can provide that class to achieve the same effect as a virtual method without the dangers. But the thing doing the registration would need practically the same property interface as PropertySpy; it seems tedious but I guess "ugly and works" is better than what I've got.

Anything I'm missing? I'll even take "it's a warning, not a rule" as an answer if the argument is convincing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario seems complicated enough to consider a completely different approach to class instantiation. What about using a factory to construct property spies?

```
public class PropertySpyFactory<T> where T : PropertySpy, new()
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        T result = new T();
        // … whatever initialization needs to be done goes here …
        result.RegisterForEvents();
        return result;
    }
}

ScenarioOnePropertySpy spy = PropertySpyFactory<ScenarioOnePropertySpy>.Create();
```

It's salvagable in the code, instance initialization can be extended easily, and once you turn to an IoC it will feel quite natural and not much refactoring will be needed.

**UPDATE:** One another option in case a) your spy hierarchy is flat enough and b) you don't need to use a common ancestor or you can substitute it with an interface:

```
public abstract class PropertySpy<T> where T : PropertySpy, new()
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        T result = new T();
        // … whatever initialization needs to be done goes here …
        result.RegisterForEvents();
        return result;
    }

    …
}

public class ScenarioOnePropertySpy : PropertySpy<ScenarioOnePropertySpy>
{
    …
}

ScenarioOnePropertySpy spy = ScenarioOnePropertySpy.Create();
```

In other words, the factory method is located right within the common ancestor. The drawback of this approach is that it isn't *that* orthogonal (the factory isn't separated from the classes being constructed) and hence less extensible and flexible. However, in certain cases may be a valid option.

Last but not least, you can create a factory method in each class again. The advantage is you can keep constructors protected and hence force users to use factory methods instead of direct instantiation.

Comment: Hmm... I really need to pass the FooBase parameter to it but I think I can do that with an extra protected method to set that property. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

The key issue I believe is that by the time the virtual method is called, your subclass constructor and initializers have not executed yet.  So, in your overridden method, your subclass may not have all the things you expect to be initialized initialized.

Comment: Right. I'm not asking, "Why is this a bad thing?". I'm asking, "Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without the risks."